# tomcat fails to connect to a logging server while starting ubuntu

Tags: networking, tomcat6, virtual-machine, socketexception, graylog2

i installed Tomcat6.0 to start at startup, using a init.d script.
while loading a web service, who tries to connect to a logging server, i get an exception:

log4j:ERROR Socket exception
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.graylog2.GelfSender.initiateChannel(GelfSender.java:29)
    at org.graylog2.GelfSender.(GelfSender.java:23)
    at org.graylog2.log.GelfAppender.activateOptions(GelfAppender.java:125)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:295)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseCategory(DOMConfigurator.java:436)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:999)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:867)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:755)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:891)

but the funny thing is that the same web service, while loading, few second later, tries to connect to a local database and succeeds.
there are 2 network interfaces, a local one, and another one for the internet.
i'm working on a virtual machine, with Ubuntu 12.04 on it.
the 2 network adapters are of type VMXNET3
any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason: it takes longer for the network adapter to load than the tomcat. 
it was on a VM.